# Вызов метода POST через ссылку

Tags: html, javascript

Вопрос возник, ссылка вида

```
<a href="myservlet?command=mycommand">show me something</a>
```

Вызывает метод `doGet` по умолчанию. Возможно ли его изменить на метод `doPost`? И если да, то как будет выглядеть код ссылки?

Comment: Вызывайте метод JavaScript, который будет отправлять то, что надо в том виде, который вам надо.

Comment: а в чем проблема вместо ссылки поставить обычную форму. для этого даже javascript'a писать ненадо 2-3 хтмл строчки. но мухин достоин уважения, постарался :)

Comment: Вопрос вызван вообще незнанием как интернет работает. Разберитесь вообще что такое GET и POST, и что такое ссылки, браузер и HTML. А уже потом занимайтесь Java и сервлетами. И тогда не будет фраз вроде "a href вызывает метод doGet", да ещё и по умолчанию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function postToUrl(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Устанавливаем метод отправки.

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    for(var key in params) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

*UPD1*:
Забыл пример вызова оставить:

```
postToUrl('путь', {'parameter' : 'parameter value'}, 'POST')
```

*UPD2*:
Такс. У меня такое чувство сложилось, что вы очень слабо представляете что такое клиентская часть и HTML-страница.
Ну так вот. Серверная часть тут не причем, когда задача стоит в отправке на сервер от клиента запрос. На вашей `HTML` или 'JSP' странице может присутствовать код `HTML` (как вы это прекрасно знаете), а также код `JavaScript`. Я не могу тут описать основы его работы и основы динамического 'HTML' или как там его еще называют. Приведу просто пример использования.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     // Сюда ставите код, который я написал первым
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" onclick="postToUrl('myservlet', {'command':'mycommand'}, 'POST'");">
</body>
```

Вот как-то так. Ну и, можете посмотреть информацию про динамический HTML, JavaScript. Без этого сайты уже никак не обходятся на сегодняшний день.

Comment: Умеете задавать событие `onClick` для элемента?

Comment: красивый код, вот только это не java код. Можно поподробнее что это и где должно находиться?
Задавать события на onClick не умею. Только недавно стал изучать.

Comment: ))) Да! Это код JavaScript, который происходит в браузере. А вам именно на ссылку надо? Может, пример с кнопкой дать?

Answer (score 2):

вот пример сервлета:

```
package edu.jtc.servlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HandlerServlet extends HttpServlet{
```

@Override
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
    {

```
    String username;
    PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
    username=request.getParameter("username");
    if (!username.equals(""))
    {
    output.print("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">"
            + "<html><head><title>Hello</title>"
            + "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"s/form-style.css\"/>"
            + "</head><body><h1>Hello</h1>"
            +"<p>Hello, "+username+"!!!</p></body></html>");
    }else{
        FormServlet serv=new FormServlet("You don't enter username");
        serv.doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

}

в web.xml пишите:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>authentication-handler-form</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.jtc.servlet.HandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>authentication-handler-form</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>handler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

вот вызов:

```
<form method="POST" action="handler">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```